# Uniform Distribution conditional?

Tags: statistics

The total time in minutes for an exam is 105 min. The time when a student submits is uniformly distributed. If a randomly chosen student has not submitted at 60 minutes what is the chance he/she will submit within next 30 minutes?

Attempt at problem:

X~U[0,105]
Let x be the time in minutes that the examination takes

Need to find `P(60<x<90 | x > 60)`

Did I set up the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes. You can typeset math with mathjax. Note that $P(60 < X < 90 | X >60) = P( 60 < X < 90 \text{ and } X>60 )/P(X>60) = P(60 < X< 90) / P(X>60)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've set it up correctly.

**Hint**

Next step to proceed with could be the notion that

$$P(A\vert B) = \frac{P(B\vert A)P(A)}{P(B)},$$
where $A = [60<x<90]$, $B = [x>60]$. Start with the value  of $P(B\vert A)$. Then everything will become clear.

Comment: Its easier just to start with the def. of conditional probability rather than using bayes' rule, since $A \cap B = A$.

Comment: @Batman, oh, yes, you're right. Nevertheless, now he has two approaches to get the same result